# Clicksend SMS gateway Pagination does not work on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on getting messages history from ClickSend API, I am trying to message from it API as there documentation. But pagination doesn't work. It's only getting the first 15 recorded. Not getting page number as parameter what I send it. Anyone know how does it do? Can I know where I am wrong?

This is my controller Method.

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $config = ClickSend\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()
            ->setUsername('user-name')
            ->setPassword('password');

        $apiInstance = new ClickSend\Api\SMSApi(new GuzzleHttp\Client(),$config);
        $page = $request->page ? $request->page: 1; // int | Page number
        $limit = 10; // int | Number of records per page

        try {

            $result = $apiInstance->smsHistoryGet($page, $limit);
            $dt = json_decode($result);
            $current_page = $dt->data;
            $current_page = $current_page->current_page;
            $next_page = $current_page+1;
            $prev_page = $current_page == 1 ? null : $current_page-1;
            $allMessages = $dt->data->data;
            return response()->json(['data' => view('staff.history.table', compact('allMessages', 'current_page', 'next_page', 'prev_page'))->render()]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception when calling SMSApi->smsHistoryGet: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

This is my blade files

```
<table id="sms-table" class="table table-hover datatable-User">
    <thead>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>Message</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($allMessages as $item)
        @if($item->status == "Received")
            <tr>
                @php $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($item->date ) @endphp
                <td>{{$date->toDayDateTimeString()}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->from}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->body}}</td>
                <td><span class="badge badge-success">{{$item->status}}</span> </td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="mt-5">
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item {{$prev_page == null ? 'disabled' : ''}}" data-page="{{$prev_page == null ? null : $prev_page }}">
                <a class="page-link" {{$prev_page == null ? 'disabled' : ''}} href="" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li>
{{--            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" >1</a></li>--}}
{{--            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">2</a></li>--}}
{{--            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">3</a></li>--}}
            <li class="page-item" data-page="{{$next_page == null ? null : $next_page }}">
                <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<script>
    $('.page-item').on('click', function () {
        var page = $(this).data('page')
        $.ajax({
            url: 'maindomain/api/all-inbound?page=' + page,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#sms-data').html(data.data);
            },

        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You're not passing in the required number of parameters, try: `$result = $apiInstance->smsHistoryGet(null, null, null, $page, $limit);`

Comment: Thanks. I t's work. Can You teach me how to pass from and to date as well? I don't have an idea how to pass it as timestamp

Comment: can you explain what you want to do in here, `how to pass from and to date as well`

Comment: Actually, @bhucho I want to pass today 00:00 And 23:59  to this from date & to date.

Comment: still not understood explain completely, @DigitalDrifter did you understood from the comment above?